# Javascript randomized countdown trigger function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I am wondering how using Javascript I can create something where there is a countdown from 3-5 seconds down to 0 seconds (randomized) and once the countdown ends, it will trigger a function and restart. If the code picks the number 3, the number 3 will appear on the screen and be wiped when the program restarts. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id = num style= 'display:none'></div>
```

Javascript:

```
//Make a random number between 3 to 5 seconds.
var ran_num = Math.floor((Math.random()*3+3)

//I am not sure what function you wanna rigger
function unknown(){};

setInterval(function(){
    console.log(ran_num)
if(ran_num === 0){
 ran_num = Math.floor((Math.random()*3+3))
unknown()
} else if(ran_num === 3){
document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = ran_num;
document.getElementById('num').style.display = 'revert'
 ran_num = parseFloat(ran_num)-1;
}else {
 document.getElementById('num').style.display = 'none'
 ran_num = parseFloat(ran_num)-1;
}

},1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried something but finding way to repeat the functon :

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var d = new Date();
var countDownDate = d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 7);

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    function myFunction() {
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
myFunction();
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```